# Python string slicing not getting intended values

Tags: python, string

I am trying to search for the sum of occurances of a substring within a string:

```
string = 'ABCDCDC'
sub_string = 'CDC'
for i in range(len(string)-len(sub_string)):
    print(string[i:len(substring)]
```

I am unsure why this is my output:

```
ABC
BC
C
```

Should'nt it be:

```
ABC
BCD
CDC
DCD
CDC
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to increment length i times to match len 3 elemnst see

```
string = 'ABCDCDC'
sub_string = 'CDC'
for i in range(len(string)-len(sub_string)):
   
    print(f'{i} to {len(sub_string)}')
```

in your case #

```
0 to 3
1 to 3
2 to 3
3 to 3
```

Code correction

```
string = 'ABCDCDC'
sub_string = 'CDC'
for i in range(len(string)-len(sub_string)):
    print(string[ i:i + len(substring)]
    print(f'{i} to {i+len(sub_string)}')
```

output #

```
0 to 3
1 to 4
2 to 5
3 to 6
```

you will get

```
ABC
BCD
CDC
DCD
```

Comment: Thank you ! This makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 1):

You have missed two things when you pass a number in range() it is exclusive of that number so for that you should add 1 to that and you have missed to add i in iteration while slicing this code will work for you.

```
string = 'ABCDCDC'
sub_string = 'CDC'
for i in range(len(string)-len(sub_string)+1):
    print(string[i: i+ len(sub_string)])
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `len(substring)` instead of `i + len(substring)`.

```
string = 'ABCDCDC'
sub_string = 'CDC'
for i in range(len(string)-len(sub_string)+1):
    print(string[i:i + len(sub_string)])
```

output:

```
ABC
BCD
CDC
DCD
CDC
```

PS: use `range(len(string)-len(sub_string)+1)` to make the loop iterate over all possible, including the final index.

Comment: Thanks, I guess it didnt occur to me that I need to increase the the second counter TILL it gets to the end of its number.

Answer (score -1):

A small change would get the expected output

**Code:**

```
string = 'ABCDCDC'
sub_string = 'CDC'
for i in range(len(string)-len(sub_string)):
    print(string[i: i+ len(sub_string)])
```

**Output**

```
ABC
BCD
CDC
DCD
```

**Reason:**

You can try priniting the len(sub_string) and see that it is constanlt 3 because length is always 3.

```
string = 'ABCDCDC'
sub_string = 'CDC'
for i in range(len(string)-len(sub_string)):
    print(i, len(sub_string))
```

**Output:**

```
0 3
1 3
2 3
3 3
```

The change that we did was **i+ len(sub_string)** we are changing the end index by adding it to the start index

Comment: @DeanChirieleison :)